# Send values to back Javascript with json and .post

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, post

All,
I have the following code:

```
$.post("save.php", {rate: value, vendor: vendor_id}, function(results)
{
    alert(results);
}, "json");
```

I get the data and do some updates to the database. When I'm done I'd like to pass back $var1, $var2. Then parse those values and put them into a div. How can I send these values back so I can access them in something like:

```
results.var1
```

Then I can put that value of var1 into a div. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create an associative array holding your data, turn it into JSON and return it:

```
$data = array('var_one' => $var1, 'var_two' => $var2);
$jsonData = json_encode($data);
echo $jsonData;
```

You can read about [manipulating elements with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) to learn about inputting the data into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In your php script, you would have to put `$var1` and `$var2` in a json object and echo out that object.

The easiest way to do that would be to put `$var1` and `$var2` in an array and do an `echo json_encode($arr);`